# How to pass an active/toggled class through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to figure out how I can pass an active class/toggle class to AJAX to send to php. I have a section where divs look like buttons allowing the user to click on one or more and then that will change to show it is active. I am wanting to send the ones that were clicked on through AJAX to my php file. I was successfully able to send my inputs through AJAX, but I am stumped on this one.

The buttons look like this:

[image]

So the ones that are active, I want to pass to AJAX.

I get my buttons to look active by doing this:

```
$('.project-option-boxes').click(function() {
  $(this).hide().toggleClass('box_focused').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

My HTML

```
<div class="project-container">
<div class="project-input-container">
<form action="" autocomplete="on" method="POST" id="project-information-form">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="project-name" placeholder="Your Name">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="title-roll" placeholder="Title/Role">
    <input type="email" class="input-borderless" id="project-email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="project-number" placeholder="Phone Number">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="project-company" placeholder="Company/URL">
</div>
<div id="project-scope-container">
    <div id="project-scope-title">PROJECT SCOPE</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">BRANDING & IDENTITY</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">WEB DESIGN</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">RESPONSIVE/MOBILE</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">MARKETING ASSETS</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">HTML5 ANIMATION</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">SEO OPTIMIZATION</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">MONTHLY SUPPORT</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">WEB DEVELOPMENT</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">ECOMMERCE</div>
</div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit-project" value="Send Project Inquiry">
</form>
</div>
```

So far for my AJAX (for the inputs) I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#submit-project").on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var project_name        = $("#project-name").val();
        var title_roll          = $("#title-roll").val();
        var project_email       = $("#project-email").val();
        var project_number      = $("#project-number").val();
        var project_company     = $("#project-company").val();
        var project_description = $("#project-description").val();
        var project_source      = $("#project-source").val();
        var project_socialMedia = $("#project-socialMedia").val();
        var project_humanTest   = $("#project-humanTest").val();        
        $.ajax({
            url: "email-project.php", 
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                "project_name":         project_name,
                "title_roll":           title_roll,
                "project_email":        project_email,
                "project_number":       project_number,
                "project_description":  project_description,
                "project_source":       project_source,
                "project_socialMedia":  project_socialMedia,
                "project_humanTest":    project_humanTest
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //console.log(data); // data object will return the response when status code is 200
                if (data == "Error!") {
                    alert("Unable to send email!");
                    alert(data);
                } else {
                    $(".project-container").addClass("removeClass");
                    $(".email-success").show();
                    $(".announcement_success").fadeIn();
                    $(".announcement_success").show();
                    $(".light-gray-container").hide();
                   // $('.announcement_success').html('Email Successfully sent!');
                   //$('.announcement_success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + "|" + errorThrown);
                //console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: What I tried.

```
    var project_company     = $("#project-company").val();
    var project_description = $("#project-description").val();
    var project_source      = $("#project-source").val();
    var project_socialMedia = $("#project-socialMedia").val();
    var project_humanTest   = $("#project-humanTest").val();
    var activeDivs = $('.project-option-boxes.box_focused').map(function(i, el){
        return $(this).html();
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "email-project.php", 
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            "project_name":         project_name,
            "title_roll":           title_roll,
            "project_email":        project_email,
            "project_number":       project_number,
            "project_description":  project_description,
            "project_source":       project_source,
            "project_socialMedia":  project_socialMedia,
            "project_humanTest":    project_humanTest,
            "activeDivs":           activeDivs
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can simply use the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and then fetch the text value of the div and push it into an array. Then pass it along with the data to the AJAX call

```
all_focused = [];
$('.project-option-boxes.box_focused').each(function(){
    all_focused.push($(this).text());
});

//Append to 'data'
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {
        ...
        "project_scope" : JSON.stringify(all_focused),
        ...
```

```js
all_focused = [];
$('.box_focused').each(function(){
  all_focused.push($(this).text());
});

console.log(all_focused);
```

```css
.box_focused {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="project-scope-container">
    <div id="project-scope-title">PROJECT SCOPE</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes box_focused">BRANDING & IDENTITY</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">WEB DESIGN</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes box_focused">RESPONSIVE/MOBILE</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">MARKETING ASSETS</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">HTML5 ANIMATION</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">SEO OPTIMIZATION</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">MONTHLY SUPPORT</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">WEB DEVELOPMENT</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes">ECOMMERCE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works except my php won't echo the data. I get this error: `Notice: Array to string conversion in /home4/fsf/public_html/asdfdsa.com/email-project.php on line 34
Your email was sent!` The email displays "Array". How could I go about fixing that?

Comment: @Becky - You can use [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in PHP. And also use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for passing the data.

Comment: So I have in php file, the data passed through like this: `$project_options  = $_POST['project_scope'];` So would I do this? : `$project_options = json_encode() = $project_options` ??

Comment: @Becky - `$project_options = $_POST['project_scope']; $options = json_encode($project_options, true)`

Comment: Cool. Both ways worked. Thank you! Do you know how I can get it out of an array format? It is sending as an array ....  ["BRANDING & IDENTITY","ECOMMERCE"]

Comment: Well, PHP is not exactly my expertise but you can try using [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to loop through the array.

Comment: @Becky - Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just filter the active divs using `.project-option-boxes.box_focused`. Then using [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) you can build an array to send-

```
var activeDivs = $('.project-option-boxes.box_focused').map(function(i, el){
            return $(this).html();
});
```

Then add that `activeDivs` to your ajax -

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "email-project.php", 
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            "project_name":         project_name,
            "title_roll":           title_roll,
            "project_email":        project_email,
            "project_number":       project_number,
            "project_description":  project_description,
            "project_source":       project_source,
            "project_socialMedia":  project_socialMedia,
            "project_humanTest":    project_humanTest,
            "activeDivs":           activeDivs  //add the array to your data
        },
        ...
```

see this [jsFiddle example - https://jsfiddle.net/kdghucwn/](https://jsfiddle.net/kdghucwn/)

Comment: How would I do this, though?   activeDivs  //add the array to your data

Comment: you put the `var activeDivs = $('.project-option-boxes.box_focused')....` right after `var project_humanTest   =....` (before your `$.ajax({...`). And you add `"activeDivs": activeDivs` to the end of your `data : {...}`

Comment: It seems this is killing the script. 2jquery.min.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: Which part is causing the error? the declaration - `var activeDivs = $('.project-option-boxes.box_focused')....` or the use `"activeDivs": activeDivs`?

Comment: It is not saying. The error is coming from a line in the jQuery library.

Comment: You could try changing the `return $(this).html();` to `return el.innerHTML;` as it may be a context error when using `$(this)` in `.map()`

Comment: That didn't help. It is showing this line specifically that is causing issues from the jQuery library. `value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : ( value == null ? "" : value );`

Comment: What version of jQuery library are you using? As [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) only works on objects in >=1.6

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I'd add an id to each element:

```
<div id="project-scope-container">
    <div id="project-scope-title">PROJECT SCOPE</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes" id="brandingAndIdentity">BRANDING & IDENTITY</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes" id="webDesign">WEB DESIGN</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes" id="responsive">RESPONSIVE/MOBILE</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes" id="marketingAssets">MARKETING ASSETS</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes" id="html5Animation">HTML5 ANIMATION</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes" id="seoOptimization">SEO OPTIMIZATION</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes" id="monthlySupport">MONTHLY SUPPORT</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes" id="webDevelopment">WEB DEVELOPMENT</div>
    <div class="project-option-boxes" id="ecommerce">ECOMMERCE</div>
</div>
```

Then I'd just set an array to and add or remove the selected options to it like so:

```
var selectedProjectOptions = [];

$('.project-option-boxes').click(function() {
    $(this).hide().toggleClass('box_focused').fadeIn('slow');

    //get the option's id
    var selectedOption = $(this).attr('id');
    //check to see if it's in the selectedProjectOptions array
    var optionIndex = selectedProjectOptions.indexOf(selectedOption);
    //If it has an index in the array already then it's being toggled off -- so we remove it.
    //If it isn't, we're adding to it.
    if(optionIndex > -1){
        selectedProjectOptions.splice(optionIndex, 1);
    } else {
        selectedProjectOptions.push(selectedOption);
    }
});
```

Then it's just a matter of adding that variable to your ajax data:

```
data: {
    ...
    "project_options": selectedProjectOptions,
}
```

EDIT: I made a fiddle for you to see how it works https://jsfiddle.net/2xxnxrdL/

Answer (score 0):

You can pass all active divs in comma separated string to apply in IN Clause of SQL as ---

```
Var actives="";
$('.project-option-   boxes  .box_focused').each(function() { 
If (actives != "")
 avtives += ","+$(this).text();
Else
actives = $(this).text();
 });
```

Pass actives in ajax parameters or use it in SQL directly in IN Clause like ----

```
Where project_scope IN(actives);
```